# Function derived column missing from export

Tags: export, ms-access-2016

I have an access query that uses a function to fill a column in a query. The data shows up when viewing the query in access.  However, when exporting the data the column is omitted.  How can I get the complete row to export?

*Details:*

In SQL view the select *AS* is used.  In design view the function is shown in the **Field:** row. There is no **table:** row dropdown option to correspond to the function(s). The show option is checked. Only the two tables in the join show in the dropdown.

[image: Show option is checked]

Datasheet view shows data as expected.

[image: Data displays as expected.]

My experience is primarily with MSSQL, my access knowledge is limited so I thank you for your patience in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot the export worked as expected.

I post this for any lurkers with the same issue.  I have no idea why it was not working, but, it is working fine now.

## AbhorThatWhichFixesItself